# Android studio new project doesn't want to compile

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to build a new project on my work mac book and the gradle pluging is a lot higher then the work project 7.6 VS 8.1.2 for new project. When I just create the basic empty activity nothing compile.

We had some intern stuff for our lib i commented the file out so nothing should interfer with the compiling. I made sure to turn off the work proxy so it shouldnt also interfer with compiling, I asked my other co-worker about this issue and they had something we could try, the new project all compile onto their machine without a probleme. it seem like only me is getting stuck here.

The error is -

```
Build file '/Users/olabelle/StudioProjects/test/build.gradle.kts' line: 2

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.1.2')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

Comment: May be instead of just telling that nothing works you edit your post and post the error message as text that you get when you try to compile the newly created project? Because otherwise your post is so sparse that only someone who can read your mind will be able to answer it.

Comment: @Robert yeah sorry, I was adding a picture of the error cause its not "code" and somehow when submitting the ticket stackoverflow removed the picture, I was adding it as you posted your comment, hopefully it help

Comment: please share your `build.gradle` files & potentially `settings.gradle`, thats where the error lies

Comment: @Blundell I could share, but its literally if you build a new Empty activity project on the latest build of Android Studio giraffe, I compared to all other friends to see if the project was different but its 100% same. nothing changed at all so the error must come from something outside, but I'm out of idea of what can interfer with that.